# Installing Dune with the help of Opam

Tags: ocaml, msys2, opam, ocaml-dune, dune

I have somehow managed to install Opam on MSYS2 on Windows.
When I open the MSYS2 MING64 (the blue one) shell and enter

```
opam --version
```

it tells me that it is installed.

When I run

```
opam install dune
```

, that command worked the first time and now it says

```
[NOTE] Package dune is already installed (current version is 3.5.0).
```

However if I then want to launch dune with

```
dune init proj myfirstocamlproject
```

it says

```
bash : dune : command not found
```

I followed also the tutorial https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Usage.html
and ran the command

```
opam init
```

It tells me in the end

```
User configuration:
  C:/Software/msys64/home/imelf/.profile is already up-to-date.
[NOTE] Make sure that C:/Software/msys64/home/imelf/.profile is well sourced in your ~/.bashrc.
```

What should it mean? Where is this file ~/.bashrc. and what does the tilde mean?

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What's your PATH?

Comment: How can I figure out the content of my PATH variable in MSYS2 ?

Comment: Try `echo $PATH`

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/opt/bin:/opt/bin

Comment: Is dune in any of those directories?

Comment: I used the Windows Explorer to search for dune.exe in C: \Software\msys64 and the path to dune.exe is C:\Software\msys64\home\imelf\.opam\ocaml-variants.4.10.0+mingw64c\bin

Comment: How can I add this path to dune to the path variable , so I don't have to do it every time I want to work with it. And how to add all the executable installed by the opam-package-manager

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the command

```
eval $(opam config env)
```

The instructions were there
https://github.com/ocaml/dune